# Rails with Neo4j: deployment onto EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, amazon-ec2, neo4j, jruby

We are building a **JRoR application with neo4j.rb**. And after some googles, we would like to use **EC2** for hosting. Also, for scalability, **HA-cluster** will be needed.

Has some done this before? Or is there a guide on this?

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I would first investigate if it's possible to use the new 3.x version of Neo4j.rb, or what is missing. The new 3.x supports the neo4j server  http api so you can deploy it on heroku. It is tricky to get the HA cluster configuration right.

Comment: did you check:
http://janitor.se/blog/2013/07/04/easier-neo4j-dot-rb-deployments-with-chef-plus-capistrano-plus-torquebox/

Comment: I recently deployed a Neo4j.rb 2.3 app to a standalone machine. Not exactly what you're looking for, but I can tell you that you should definitely use Torquebox and take advantage of it as much as possible. It has native clustering support for the app, though you'll still need to configure the Neo4j cluster separately. I found http://pragprog.com/book/jkdepj/deploying-with-jruby helpful when I was researching, though it's a little out of date now as far as Torquebox is concerned.